# Почему при нажатии кнопки в tkinter открывается еще одно окно tkinter?

Tags: python, многопоточность, tkinter

Когда нажимаю на кнопку START почему-то открывается еще одно окно tkinter.

```
def stop():
    global processes
    for process in processes:
        process.terminate()

def strt():
    global threadId
    for logindata in loginsdata:
        if threadId < 10:
            threadId += 1
            login = logindata.split(':')[0]
            password = logindata.split(':')[1]
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=mainframe, args=(login, password,))
            process.start()
            processes.append(process)
            resarr.append(str('thread ' + str(threadId) + 'started for' + login))
            time.sleep(1)
    return 0
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('370x195')
frame = Frame(root, bg='#d3d3d3')
frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
paus = Button(frame, text='STOP', bg='red', command=stop)
paus.pack()
paus.place(height=20, width=60, x=305, y=5)
strt = Button(frame, text='START', bg='green', command=strt)
strt.pack()
strt.place(height=20, width=60, x=5, y=5)
label = Label(frame, text='', bg='white', height=2, width=6, anchor='nw')
label.pack()
label.place(x=5, y=30, height=160, width=360)
label.config(text='\n'.join(resarr[:10]))

root.mainloop()
```

Почему так происходит? Ведь в функции strt нет повторной инициализации окна
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: Добавьте весь код в вопрос (либо не весь, но так чтобы код хотя бы запускался). По поводу появления нового окна - поместите весь код вне функций кроме импортов в блок `if __name__ == '__main__':`. multiprocessing фактически создает новый процесс интерпретатора, в котором импортирует текущий модуль, потом вызывает указанную функцию. Из-за того что у вас на верхнем уровне модуля весь код вне блока `if __name__ == '__main__':`, то он заново выполняется при импорте модуля.

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно помогло